# Onclick function is Not Working on my AMP WebSite

Tags: amp-html

I have created AMP site using AMP plugins On my site, I want to perform "Click to Call Action" in a popup. I have tried Onclick function on my site but, It is not working. How do i perform Click to Call action in popup?

Comment: What do you want to show in popup? You can use amp-lightbox.

Answer (score 2):

`onClick()` is a javascript function and AMP does not allow you to use custom javascript code in an AMP page. But you can still achieve the desired functionality by using `on` attribute in AMP ([Read Docs](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/interaction_dynamic/amp-actions-and-events)). Using `on` attribute on an element you can define what action to peform when any of the supported events occurs (in your case `tap`; same as click).

For Example `<div role="none" tabIndex="0" on="tap:redButton.hide"> ... </div>`.

Although it may seem impossible, a lot of common functionalities can be recreated using AMP components, without using custom javascript.